# Auto Arrange UIViews when adding them programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I want to add programmatically an unknown number of sub views into a UIView. Is it possible to use auto layout to auto arrange these subviews, like the below picture:

[image: aut-arrange]

I am using iOS8, objective-c, XCode, iPad
Thanks,

Comment: try storing those in a collection view maybe it will do the job

Comment: Can you be clearer? thanks

Comment: i mean you just give a random number of cells you need in the UICollection View and it will automatically put those with this design itself

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about UICollection View

Comment: No prob .. are you new to this ?

Comment: you can use Autolayout size classes

Comment: Yes, I am new to UICollectionView

Comment: Can you be clearer with autolayout size classes?

Comment: the subviews in the UICollectionView are not auto arranged as I expected.